# Is it possible to use GDK to get the image/pixel data of any arbitrary X11 window using the window's name?

Tags: x11, python, gtk

**Summary**

I am writing a script (in Python 3.X) to do image detection on a number of different GUI's in Linux. Can GDK be used to get a pixel buffer of any X11 window? If so, how? I am currently using the [`wnck` library](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/index.html)

I'm aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-on-linux), but it only shows getting the current processes window.

**Elaboration**

When I say "image data" i'm essentially referring to a screenshot, but I don't necessarily care about saving it. A pixel buffer might be the more appropriate terminology.

This is a variation of a question [I asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618687/obtain-image-data-of-separate-application-using-python3-on-linux?noredirect=1) about how to achieve getting image data specifically with Python.

To prevent an XY problem: I need to do some image detection on GUIs running in both Linux and Windows. I have working code for Windows 10 that gets an applications image data using the win32 API and puts it into a numpy array for using with OpenCV. I now need a similar approach for Linux. I have started researching X11 and available python libraries, but I keep coming back to a thread that shows using `gdk` in python to get the screenshot of the invoking process. I want to be able to do it for any X11 window.

Comment: Does `xwd` fit your needs? It can dump by name. `imagemagick` can convert the format into more common ones.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, if it's performant enough for my needs (using object detection with OpenCV) i'll post an answer in the linked StackOverflow thread. Cheers!